# Can I set the default resolution for a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, wordpress, configuration

I'm posting some YouTube videos on my WordPress blog, but they always default to 360p, even though I've provided the &hd=1 parameter. The videos can go up to 1080p if the user selects it, and I'd like to set a default of at least 720p. I don't care if they bump it down or not.

Can this be done?

Comment: The hd=1 parameter [like so](http://www.psmdigital.com/blog/how-to-embed-a-youtube-video-in-hd-on-your-website/)?

Comment: Well, to embed it in WordPress I found I had to just link directly to the video. Adding the HTML for the embed didn't work for me.

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582336/force-youtube-embed-to-start-in-720p

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can set the resolution for the user. YouTube's horrible embedded player is AFAIK the same as the horrible player on their webpage, which means the resolution is configured by the user and not the poster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `hd=1&`, not just the `hd=1`.  Without the ampersand, it won't work.

Follow our post [here.](http://www.psmdigital.com/blog/how-to-embed-a-youtube-video-in-hd-on-your-website/)

Comment: Only if the parameter is *not* the last, i.e. it's followed by other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Add this argument to your query string: `&vq=hd720`

For example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/n6fUZ5eFaPc?autoplay=1&vq=hd1440
```